# replace string in XML file python

Tags: python, xml, file

I want to replace all the strings (Except the image filename, only change those in the name tags) 'bicycle' in the xml file with 'bike'. I wanted to do with re.sub by using .readlines(), but that's not working. Can anyone advise how can I do that in the most efficient way (A good explanation will be of much help)?

```
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>bicycle (10).jpg</filename>
    <path>C:\Users\Merida\Desktop\Bicycle\images\bicycle (10).jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>960</width>
        <height>636</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>bicycle</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>68</xmin>
            <ymin>24</ymin>
            <xmax>755</xmax>
            <ymax>632</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>bicycle</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1</xmin>
            <ymin>28</ymin>
            <xmax>189</xmax>
            <ymax>435</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to replace text in xml or python?

Comment: I want to replace the string bicycle with bike in the xml file by reading it using python

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Do mean that you want to read it like a text file `.read()` and then replace all of the replace all of the words that contains `bicycle` with `bike` or like the image named `bicycle.jpg` you want to replace specific things `<name> bicycle</name>` with `<name> bike</name>`

Comment: I want to change those only in the name tags, except the filename

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace ALL occurrences of "bicycle" it can be easily done with 'replace':

```
input_file = "example.xml"
output_file = "output.xml"
with open(input_file) as f:
    xml_content = f.readlines()
    
with open(output_file, 'w+') as f:
    for line in xml_content:
        f.write(line.replace('bicycle', 'bike'))
```

However, if you want to keep the structure of your xml intact (in case an element or attribute name would be bicycle) you might wanna take a look at [elementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml](https://lxml.de/).

Edit: after the edit of your question here a cleaner solution with elementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
input_file = "example.xml"
output_file = "output.xml"

tree = ET.parse(input_file)
root = tree.getroot()
name_elts = root.findall(".//name")    # we find all 'name' elements

for elt in name_elts:
    elt.text = elt.text.replace("bicycle", "bike")

tree.write(output_file)
```

Comment: This solution with ET worked. Did it for a batch of files with a loop.

Answer (score 2):

This was my approach, this will replace all instances of "bicycle" with "bike". This will also change "bicycle" in the path that you specified, which I think is what you were looking for. Also "text.xml" would need to be replaced with the name of the file you used

```
# Open file containing xml text and copy contents to string
f = open("test.xml", "r+")
xmlText = f.read()

# Bring pointer back to start of file and delete all contents
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()

# Replace all instances of bicycle with bike
newText = xmlText.replace("bicycle", "bike")

# Write this new text with replaced words to the file and close
f.write(newText)
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I actually overlooked the bicycle in the file name then, sorry

Comment: I also wanted to use this approach, but this approach doesn't keep the xml properties as much as I've learnt. I need to keep all the xml properties.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following XSLT based solution.

The XSLT is following a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

It will modify `<name>` element values from 'bicycle' to 'bike', leaving everything else intact.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>bicycle (10).jpg</filename>
    <path>C:\Users\Merida\Desktop\Bicycle\images\bicycle (10).jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>960</width>
        <height>636</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>bicycle</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>68</xmin>
            <ymin>24</ymin>
            <xmax>755</xmax>
            <ymax>632</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>bicycle</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1</xmin>
            <ymin>28</ymin>
            <xmax>189</xmax>
            <ymax>435</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name[.='bicycle']">
        <xsl:copy>bike</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<annotation>
  <folder>images</folder>
  <filename>bicycle (10).jpg</filename>
  <path>C:\Users\Merida\Desktop\Bicycle\images\bicycle (10).jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>960</width>
    <height>636</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>bike</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>68</xmin>
      <ymin>24</ymin>
      <xmax>755</xmax>
      <ymax>632</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>bike</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>1</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>1</xmin>
      <ymin>28</ymin>
      <xmax>189</xmax>
      <ymax>435</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: is it possible to do for multiple files? Actually I want to make this change to many xml files and I was planning to do so with a for loop in python.

Comment: Sure. Just loop through the XML files in Python and apply XSLT transformation for each of them one by one